# Revealing a UITableViewCell when tapping on another

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert, tableview

The interaction I want for my UITableView is when a user taps a certain cell (specifically, row 1), another UITableView will slide out under that cell, with the cells below sliding down with it (almost like a "drawer" effect).

So far I've put the table view I want to show/hide in a cell. When the user taps the cell at row 1, I add the cell identifier for the cell to be revealed to the backing data array for the main table view. I then call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`, passing it an `IndexPath` of `2,0`. I'm not entirely sure what the method does as the documentation is pretty vague and there are not a lot of resources on the internet that explain what it does.

When tapping on the cell at row 1, I get the following errors:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:7524
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

My `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is pretty straightforward:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.tableCells[indexPath.row]];

    [self addFullWidthSeparatorsForCell: cell];

    return cell;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try to check if cell is nil.

Comment: @dizzyboy I have register all nibs with the table view, so it should never return nil. I have the prototype cells in the table view hooked up as well.

Comment: that's the error usually when the returned cell is nil. Try to add an if statement before return if(cell == nil)

Comment: also this is a suggestion for what you're trying to do with the drawer effect 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n-c5MqMSuI

Comment: Turned out to be a typo with the cell reuse identifiers. The one time I don't use static identifiers....   Thank you for your suggestions though!